# What value of thinning is acceptable in Bayesian data analysis?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, jags

I am running a poisson regression in rjags. I observed that my trace plots do not converge very well when I use a thin=10 but they all do converge pretty well when I use a thin=1.

What is the implication of using thin=1 rather than thin=10 in the interpretation in this case?

Is this really an issue with my modeling process?

Comment: Thinning has nothing to do with Bayesian analysis, it is concerned with the convergence of an MCMC sequence. Without thinning, correlation between the points may slow down convergence or worse give the impression of convergence while the chain has not visited the entire space. The thinning factor intends to reproduce iid sampling.

Comment: @Xi'an thank for the correction. In this case do you have any idea where the convergence seems better with a thinning of 1 rather than with a thinning of 10?